# Java True If Last Numbers Are 0

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input

I am trying to make a java program that will allow the user to enter any amount of numbers.  If they enter a 0, the program will say the tree is false.  I got that to work but I want it so if the last two numbers entered have are 0 the program will print true.  The 0 represents null

For example if they enter 5 numbers:

2 4 5 0 0 = true

2 0 5 0 0 = false

2 4 5 6 7 = true

All that other stuff was confusing so I simplified it

```
    System.out.println("Enter a number or enter 0 to represent null: ");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        if(arr[i] == 0)
        {
            isTree = false;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Is this a tree: " + isTree);
```

Comment: Please explain more about what the zeros mean.  The difference in behavior between your first two examples is not clear.  What do you mean by the tree is false?

Comment: @Sasha Binary search Tree i guess

Answer (score 0):

Do what you are doing, but also check for two zeros at the end:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number or enter 0 to represent null: ");
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    arr[i] = input.nextInt();
    if(arr[i] == 0 && i < arr.length-2) //ignore if last two nodes
    {
        isTree = false;
    }
}
boolean isTree2 = (arr[arr.length-1] == 0 && arr[arr.length-2] == 0)
               || (arr[arr.length-1] != 0 && arr[arr.length-2] != 0);
System.out.println("Is this a tree: " + (isTree && isTree2));
```

Comment: I did this but when the user enters 2 4 5 0 0 it still prints out false

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex "**[1-9]+0{2}**" => one or more number between 1 to 9 and finish with 2 zero.

Example with your code :

```
System.out.println("Enter a number or enter 0 to represent null: ");
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1-9]+0{2}");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("20500");
boolean isTree = false;
while(matcher.find()) {
    isTree = true;
}
System.out.println("Is this a tree: " + isTree);
```

You can try this tool for test your regex : https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want that if last two digits are zero then your program will say its true.

```
int length = arr.length;
boolean isTree = false;
if(length >= 2) {
    if(arr[length-1] == 0 && arr[length-2] == 0) {
        isTree = true;
    }
}
System.out.println(isTrue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   System.out.println("Enter a number or enter 0 to represent null: ");
   boolean cond = false;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        if(arr[i] == 0){
            cond = true;
        }
        if(arr[i] !=0 && cond){
            isTree = true;
             break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Is this a tree: " + isTree);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother checking as you're entering input, but check after all inputs have been made.  I would concatenate all your inputs into a string and then evaluate the string to determine if it satisfies your tree condition.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int num = 5;
    int[] arr = new int[num];

    System.out.println("Enter a number or enter 0 to represent null: ");
    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        // Arrays.toString(arr) results in [2, 4, 5, 0, 0]
        // Remove all brackets, commas, and spaces
        String inputs = Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll(", ", "");

        boolean isTree = true;
        // Only have to check for ending 00 if you know a 0 is in your inputs
        if (inputs.contains("0")) {
            isTree = inputs.endsWith("00") && !inputs.substring(0, inputs.length() - 2).contains("0");
        }

        System.out.println("Is this a tree: " + isTree);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]